# MockMVC not working with Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, mockmvc, spring-test-mvc

I'm using Spring Data Rest with a custom controller.

The custom controller overrides only the PATCH/PUT and POST verbs.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void updateTest() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .patch("/api/v1/users/1")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(updateString);
    
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
                .andExpect(content().json(updateString))
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

For some reason `mockMvc.perform` always return a 404 but I expect a 204. How to fix this?

Comment: There aren't enough details to reproduce this scenario, but my guess is that "/api/v1/users/1" isn't actually the URL being wired up by the `UserController`.  At a minimum, we'd need to see how the URL is being configured in the application.  Also your `UserController` (with details simplified to a minimal reproducible example) would likely help.